# Generic variable tree Error infinity loop

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I am creating a variable tree, but I've got an error, seemingly in the insert or print_wevr function.

When I run the program I get an infinite loop.

How can I go about this?

```
/*5 - VarTrees*/

/*var_trees.c*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "var_trees.h"

/*Defining the struture of variable tree.
 * The nodes has tree fields: 
      info: an generic information
      first: the first child-node
      next: the next sibling-node
 */

struct var_tree{
    void* info;
    Var_Tree* first;
    Var_Tree* next;
};

/*Create the tree*/
Var_Tree* create(void* info)
{
    Var_Tree* t = (Var_Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Var_Tree));
    t->info = info;
    t->first = NULL;
    t->next = NULL;
    return t;
}

/*Insert a node*/
void insert(Var_Tree* t,Var_Tree* st)
{
    st->next = t->first;
    t->first = st;
}

/*go_through the tree*/
void go(Var_Tree* t, void (*cb)(void*))
{
    Var_Tree* p;
    cb(t->info);
    for(p = t->first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        go(t,cb);
    printf(">");
}

/*Remove a node*/
//void remov(Var_Tree* t, void* info);


/*5 - VarTrees*/

/*main.c*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "var_trees.h"

Var_Tree* create_int(int info)
{
    return create(&info);
}

void print_int(void* info)
{
    int* t = (int*) info;
    printf("<%d",*t);
}

int main(void)
{
    Var_Tree* a = create_int(4);
    Var_Tree* b = create_int(3);
    Var_Tree* c = create_int(23);
    Var_Tree* d = create_int(1);
    Var_Tree* e = create_int(2);

    insert(a,b);
    go(a,print_tree);
}
```

The function `create_int` is a function for creating a node with the field info as int.

`print_int` is a callback function that prints an integer (the '<' creates a type of textual notation for trees).

Comment: You have an obvious error in the `go` function. Your recursive call is `go(t,cb)`, which just passes the same node to the recursive call. I think you meant `go(p,cb)`.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in `go` function, you are making a recursive call without changing the parameters that eventually lead to infinite recursion.

```
  void go(Var_Tree* t, void (*cb)(void*))
{
    Var_Tree* p;
    cb(t->info);
    for(p = t->first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        go(t,cb); //<-----here you are calling the same 
    function with the same parameter that leads to an infinite loop
    printf(">");
}
```

You should pass the value of `p` in place of `t`.

```
void go(Var_Tree* t, void (*cb)(void*))
{
    Var_Tree* p;
    cb(t->info);
    for(p = t->first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        go(p,cb);  //<----change t to p
    printf(">");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was a really silly mistake. But other error persists.
The output is <21869<21869>>
This is not what I've expected

Comment: @AndréRodrigues post another question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and we will try to help you

Comment: @AndréRodrigues You should learn how to use the debugger. By single-stepping your code, you can find errors like this much more quickly than you can by writing a question and asking somebody else to solve the problem for you. Plus, you learn more that way.